# How do I draw an arrow in Acorn?

Tags: graphics, image-editing, drawing

Yes, I know [Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/) isn't Visio, but still let me ask the question:

How can you draw an arrow with Acorn?

I am talking about the kind of arrows that Skitch or Jing would draw, and that you typically add to a screenshot to take the viewer's attention to part of the image.

[image: Example of an arrow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acorn doesn't really have native support for complex shapes / arrows like Skitch does - however, you can make an arrow using the Bezier pen tool.  You'd select it from the vector tools palette, and click around until you got your arrow.  It'll be super annoying to rotate or resize however, and it probably won't look as good.

Adding something like this has been on the todo list for a long long time, so hopefully it'll happen in a future release.

-gus

Comment: Gus, thank you for taking the time to chime in. Acorn is awesome tool, and I just wanted to make sure I didn't overlook anything. I'm certainly looking forward to this feature being added in the future.

Comment: I second this feature request